# Is Joda Time deprecated with java 8 Date and Time API? (java.time)

Tags: java-8, jodatime, deprecated, java-time

Is there any reason to use Joda Time if I can use Java 8 Date and Time API (`java.time`)?
Should I use Java 8 Date and Time every time?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The official statement of the author of Joda-time himself is to **migrate as soon as Java-8 is available**. See also this citation from the [website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
>   No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
>   to java.time (JSR-310).

So the short answer to your question is: YES (deprecated). However, keep in mind that some features like Joda-`Interval` or `PeriodType` or `PeriodFormatter` are not available in Java-8 so you have to write your own partially ugly workarounds, see also my [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631909/differences-between-java-8-date-time-api-java-time-and-joda-time/24635657#24635657) about differences between Joda-Time and JSR-310.

Side remarks about the future of both libraries:

**What does "finished" means in this context?**

Well, you can compare the [Joda-issue 254](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/254) with my [small discussion on Twitter](https://twitter.com/menohoch/status/545630331035217920). I think people should rather set down their expectations to any major enhancement of Joda-Time. Please also consider that the future development resources regarding Joda-Time are limited (lack of manpower). And let's be honest: Most releases since Joda-Time in year 2008 rather have the character of bugfix releases (with the exception of 2.0).

On the other side: The innovation speed of JSR-310 will probably not be very high, too (because it is already big, and because Oracle is here the decisive player and a date-time-library is in general not considered as the central cornerstone of any Java-release). So there is always some space left for an external library in the future to supply missing features, for example (in alphabetical order):

- [Threeten-Extra](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra) (as the favourite of Basil Bourque, see his comment)
- [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) (my own extension, interoperability issue solved in summer 2015)

Comment: [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) is one such external library supplying features missing in java.time.  (To explain the name, JSR 310 defines java.time.)

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks, I know Threeten-Extra, but am not impressed. It lacks manpower, too, and I can see some serious quality problems. You should also take a look at my library which will offer excellent interoperability with JSR-310 latest in June/July this year.

Comment: I don't see any link here to your library, nor its name.