# How define a insertion time in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to define in my Entity a `insert_time` field that automatically is generated by Hibernate when persisting it.

I am using `java.util.LocalDateTime` with `@CreationTimestamp` but it is still null in DB. I am using H2.
In addition, I would like to use joda instead.

Comment: Hibernate 5.4 supports LocalDateTime: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CreationTimestamp.html; Hibernate 4 does not: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CreationTimestamp.html. What version are you using? If you're using Java 8+, the Joda maintainers recommend sticking to the JDK classes (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750221/is-joda-time-deprecated-with-java-8-date-and-time-api-java-time)

Comment: I am using spring boot starter data 2.1.3-RELEASE.
According to the Maven reppository, it is using 5.3.7 and there is an update  5.4.2-final.

Comment: I have imported the 5.4.2 version of hibernate core and I still see NULL in database for date_time annotated with `@CreationTimestamp` of java.time.

Comment: what's the field type of date_time that's annotated with @CreationTimestamp?

Comment: java.time.LocalDateTime;

Comment: Finally It worked using 
`@Column(columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")` and removing the `@CreationTimestamp`.

Comment: Seems relevant: http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2018/03/14/dont-use-localdatetime/