# Hibernate 5 - can not cast Date to LocalDate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My query executes but when returning results, it seems to have an issue with then converting the DATE to LOCALDATE.

this is the only place in my application i have an issue with LocalDate - it works with other queries?

hibernate version: 5.4.33.FINAL

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Date cannot be cast to class org.joda.time.LocalDate (java.util.Date is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.joda.time.LocalDate is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @46b2dcc5)
```

This is the column details in my table

```
DATE_EFFECTIVE  DATE
```

This is my mapping file - it is the dateEffective column which is causing issues.

```
    <class table="DATA_POINT" 
        name="com.application.data.domain.datapoint.AbstractDataPoint" 
        proxy="com.application.data.domain.datapoint.DataPoint"
        abstract="true"
    >
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" precision="20" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">DATA_POINT_ID_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <discriminator column="DATA_POINT_TYPE" type="string" />
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="64" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="product" type="Product">
            <column name="PRODUCT" length="16" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="description" type="string">
            <column name="DESCRIPTION" length="128" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="networkObject" class="com.amor.ngc.application.network.domain.AbstractNgcNetworkObject">
            <column name="NETWORK_OBJECT_ID" not-null="false"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="dateEffective" type="LocalDate">
            <column name="DATE_EFFECTIVE" length="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
```

I have the relevant getters and setters

```
    public LocalDate getDateEffective() {
        return dateEffective;
    }

    public void setDateEffective(LocalDate dateEffective) {
        this.dateEffective = dateEffective;
    }
```

here is the full stacktrace

```
An error occurred during execution of handler: com.web.mvc.composition.ViewMonthlyGasDeliveryCompositionController#display(WebRequest, ViewMonthlyGasDeliveryCompositionSearchCriteria)
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Date cannot be cast to class org.joda.time.LocalDate (java.util.Date is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.joda.time.LocalDate is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @46b2dcc5)
    at com.application.core.dao.hibernate.usertype.JodaLocalDateUserType.nullSafeSet(JodaLocalDateUserType.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:648)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPreparedStatement(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2102)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2034)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2843)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2825)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2657)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2652)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1636)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.uniqueResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1646)
    at com.application.data.dao.hibernate.AbstractDataPointHibernateDao.findEffectiveByNetworkObjectAndNameAndProduct(AbstractDataPointHibernateDao.java:86)
    at com.application.data.dao.hibernate.VolumeDataPointHibernateDao.findEffectiveByNetworkObjectAndNameAndProduct(VolumeDataPointHibernateDao.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.findEffectiveByNetworkObjectAndNameAndProduct(Unknown Source)
    at com.application.data.domain.datapoint.DataPointManagerImpl.getVolumeDataPoint(DataPointManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.application.network.domain.AbstractNetworkObject.getVolumeDataPoint(AbstractNetworkObject.java:51)
    at com.application.network.domain.AbstractMeteredPoint.createMonthlyGasData(AbstractMeteredPoint.java:413)
    at com.application.composition.domain.CompositionDataRootImpl.getDeliveryPointTotalGasData(CompositionDataRootImpl.java:415)
    at com.service.composition.CompositionServiceImpl.getMonthlyTotalCommingledGasData_aroundBody68(CompositionServiceImpl.java:1263)
    at com.service.composition.CompositionServiceImpl$AjcClosure69.run(CompositionServiceImpl.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:67)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:73)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:71)
    at com.service.composition.CompositionServiceImpl.getMonthlyTotalCommingledGasData(CompositionServiceImpl.java:1252)
    at com.web.mvc.composition.ViewMonthlyGasDeliveryCompositionController.display(ViewMonthlyGasDeliveryCompositionController.java:122)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:152)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

this is my query - i convert the localDate to a Date so it is accepted

```
    public DataPoint findEffectiveByNetworkObjectAndNameAndProduct(NetworkObject<Long> networkObject, String dataPointName, Product product, LocalDate gasDay) {
        Query query = getSession().createQuery(findDataPointApplicableOnDateByNameQuery)
                .setParameter("name", dataPointName)
                .setParameter("gasDay", convertToDate(gasDay))
                .setParameter("product", product)
                .setParameter("networkObject", networkObject); 
        
        return (DataPoint) query.uniqueResult();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `org.joda.time.LocalDate` instead of `java.time.LocalDate`?  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/29750221/685806

Comment: working on a tech stack upgrade for this application. Theres 1000s of occurrences of org.joda.time.LocalDate so was hoping i could just leave it be.

Comment: yeah had a look through the codebase and it could be done but its a massive effort - hoping for another solution

Comment: agreed but due to time constraints, it isnt the first on the list - also lol wish it was as simple as that - i did that and theres still hundreds of methods that would need updated.